# openshift cannot enter web2py administrative page

Tags: passwords, admin, openshift, web2py

I am not an IT person, using ubuntu 12.10.
I am trying to setup sahana software in openshift. I followed the guidelines from [this page](http://eden.sahanafoundation.org/wiki/InstallationGuidelines/OpenShift). It works fine until the point where I should use administrative interface. I tried every single possible password related to openshift, but none worked. It also only gave me four chances.

The guideline said, "Once your app is up you'll need administrative access to continue. For the admin app to work you need to put your password hash in parameters_8080.py in wsgi/web2py/."
I found the parameters_80.py but have no clear idea what to do with it. I tried to use htpasswd to create a new parameters_80.py but the admin interface still rejected me.

Can someone help me?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think this thread seems to answer your question https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/web2py/DJvC9FMNohE/NykebQn5eUQJ

Comment: yes. i read that address before. and i tried it, but does not work for me. probably because i dont know how to get a "password hash" for my parameters_8080.py.

Comment: i did try from my laptop ubuntu using web2py -a blablabla. it creates a file, and i copy-paste the content to my parameters_8080.py. git add ., git commit, and git push. but when i use my browser to access https://demo-amarylis.rhcloud.com, it still does not accept my password.

Comment: EUREKA. finally it works. i remove all of my parameters_*.py and do web2py -p 8080 -a [my password]. and then create symlink: ln -s parameters_8080.py parameters_443.py 
ln -s parameters_8080.py parameters_80.py ln -s parameters_8080.py parameters_8000.py. and of course git add ., git commit, and then git push. Hopefully this can also help other newbie.